# Jquery only add without removing class

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need some help with jquery.I need my menu button to change from "menu button" to "x"(which is cancel button).But the problem is that jquery only adds the class in console and in inspector,and it even doesnt change menu icon..
Only says that the class is added...
Here is my code:

```js
$('.tablet-icon').click(function() {
  if ($('.tablet-icon').hasClass('form-active')) {
    $('.tablet-icon').removeClass('form-active');
    console.log('is-removed');
    return false;
  } else {
    $('.tablet-icon').addClass('form-acive');
    console.log('is-added');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.tablet-icon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 85%;
  top: 22px;
  width: 40px;
}
.tablet-icon:before {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  display: block;
  font-family: "ElegantIcons";
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  content: "\61";
}
.tablet-icon:before::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.tablet-icon.form-active:before {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: .9em;
  content: "\4d";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="tablet-icon"></span>
```

PM:Im working on wordpress.

Comment: you have a typo: `$('.tablet-icon').addClass('form-acive');` <- missing a t in active, if thats the problem :)

Comment: nice catch ilwcss!

Comment: That's the whole error!  @ilwcss

Comment: Hahahaha thanks mate that as <3

Answer (score 1):

Credits to **ilwcss**

**Problem:** is with this line

`$('.tablet-icon').addClass('form-acive');`

A typo error.. `form-acive` must be `form-active`

Just use `toggleClass()` to simplyfy the task.

`$('.tablet-icon').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('form-active');
 });`

Comment: @ilwcss you are an eagle. :)